# The idea of "generators" for arbitrary categories

Tags: category-theory

Given a partial order $\langle X, \leq \rangle$ and a subset $I \subseteq X$ it is common to consider $I$ as the generators of the set $\{ x \in X: i \leq x \textrm{ for some }i \in I  \}$ (i.e., the up-set generated by the elements of $I$).

On the other hand, partial orders can be seen as a very particular simple type of categories: those ones where for every two objects there is at most one arrow among them.

I wonder which are the categorical generalizations of the previous "generator" notion. In other words, is there some well known notion(s) for arbitrary categories which plays the role of "generating"?

Comment: Googling for «generator category» brings up, as first result, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_%28category_theory%29 The definition there is for a single object; you can immediately generalize that to generting sets or classes.

Comment: @Mariano: I am afraid that this wikipedia notion does not coincide with the one I have written above for partial orders (although the same word "generator" is used), so it is not adequate for what I really want to generalize.

Comment: The sets you describe, {x∈X|i≤x}i∈I is called the filter generated by I in order theory. This notion translates to left ideals in category theory: if I is a get of arrows in a category C, then {f∘i|cod(i)=dom(f)}i∈I. I haven't seen much use of this notion, but it is definitely there.

The dual notion of ideal in order theory similarly translates to right ideals in categories. This notion also goes by the name of a sieve, in particular when used in relation to Grothendieck topologies.

Comment: @espen180: Be careful because the upset generated is not the same thing than the filter generated. The notion of filter is isually used in the context of lattices (a particular kind of partial orders), and filters are always closed under finite meets, while upsets might not be closed under finite meets.

Comment: @boumol Thanks for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can consider pretty much the same thing; e.g. given a set $X$ of arrows, you can consider the set of arrows $\{ x \circ f \mid x \in X \} $, or the reverse, or a two-sided thing.

A particularly notable special case is that of a *sieve*, where we consider the set generated as above, but all of the arrows of $X$ have codomain to be a single object of the category.

The notion of a *Grothendieck topology* on a category involves sieves: a topology is a way of specifying which sieves on an object count as a "cover" of that object. If you have a generating set for the sieve, you can imagine each of the generators as specifying one set in the covering. (and all of the other arrows in the sieve are just throwing in all of the refinements of the covering, in a similar way that in ordinary topology, one usually talks about a topology, rather than a basis for the topology)

---

There is a standard term "generator" in category theory, but it's unrelated to the notion you describe: a generator is a set of objects (often a single object) with the property that if $f,g : A \to B$ are two different arrows, then there is an arrow $h:X \to A$ where $X$ is in the generating set with the property that $f \circ h \neq g \circ h$.

One way to interpret how this "generates" a category is that you can imagine replacing each object $A$ of the category with the set of all arrows $X \to A$ where $X$ is in the generating set. We can also interpret morphisms as ordinary functions on these sets (the function you get by composition).

This construction gives a functor, and the condition to be a generating set says that it is a *faithful* functor. So, the generating set can be thought of as generating the category in the sense that it produces "enough elements" to be able to properly distinguish the structure of the category.

Comment: I am not able to understand what you mean with "$\{ x \circ f \mid x \in X \}$"; can you tell me what is $f$?

Comment: @boumol: $f$ ranges over all arrows of the category for which the composition is defined.